# Using the verb "seem"

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

I made up these sentences:

1. "They seem to go to school."
2. "They seem to have gone to school."

Are they correct?

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I know what my mistake is. 

Comment: Does "they seem to be attending school" mean "it seems they attend (go to) school" or "it seems they are at school at the moment"?  It may be a silly question but I need to know exactly, please help me.

Comment: "They seem to be attending school" **can be both**: right now and these days or at this time in their lives.

Comment: "They seem to have fought each other" means "it seems they fought each other", right?

Comment: Yes, the past tense is not LIKE the present tense here.